# Correct way to check for table support in word js add-in

Tags: office-js

I'm currently using word 2016 on the deferred channel, and the production CDN for the office.js files.

I'm struggling to find the correct way to do runtime checks for table support.

Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('WordApi', 1.1) returns a true;
Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('WordApi', 1.3) returns a false;

However all of the interactions i do with the table collection work just fine.  Is there a better way to do the runtime check?  I need to gracefully handle the condition where the tables are unavailable and am not seeing a good way to do this.

In environments that don't support tables:
var tables = context.document.body.tables; 
the above tables var is defined.  It just errors on load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way for checking it is to Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('WordApi', 1.3) . All table functionality is in 1.3

Right now we are in the middle of a transition of moving the library from preview to production, and that's why its working, but some functionalities might not be supported. so i strongly recommend you to believe in the isSetSupported method.

thanks.

Comment: Any idea of when this transition should be complete?

Comment: its going to be announced at Build 2017. In just a few weeks :)